# Como usar un diccionario de un fichero a otro

Tags: python, python-3.x, diccionarios, python-import

Tengo dos ficheros, el primero se llama `science.py` y el segundo `compact.py`. En cada uno tengo un diccionario con datos. El diccionario del primer fichero de llama `sc_keys` y el del segundo `comp_keys`.

El diccionario `sc_keys` lo construyo de la siguiente forma:

```
if __name__ = '__main__':
    sc_keys = {}
    for k in clean_keys: #clean_keys es una lista con todas las palabras
        k_build = process(k) # En process() se añade el contenido del diccionario
        sc_keys[k_build] = {}
```

La duda que tengo es que quiero usar el diccionario del primer fichero al del segundo para así poder comparar-los.

En el segundo fichero tengo puesto lo siguiente:

```
from science.py import *
```

Teniendo esto me detecta que existe el diccionario `sc_keys` y que proviene del fichero `science.py`, pero cuando quiero usar-lo me sale el siguiente error:

> NameError: name 'sc_keys' is not defined

Porque no puedo usar el diccionario en el fichero `compact.py`? Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿ Que significa `lo construyo dentro de un main` ? Por favor, muestra un [mcve] que reproduzca el problema. Un saludo.

Answer (score 0):

El intérprete está funcionando exactamente de la manera que se espera que funcione.

*(Nota: daré por hecho que falta un =)*

La declaración de `sc_keys` está dentro de `if __name__ == '__main__':` por lo que sólo se ejecutará cuando el intérprete lance diréctamente ese script (usando por ejemplo `python science.py`).

Si en lugar de ejecutar el script lo importamos, la variable de entorno `__name__` tomará como valor el nombre del archivo (sin .py) y no se cumplirá la igualdad, por lo tanto `from science import *` no tiene esa variable disponible.

Comment: De acuerdo lo entiendo, pero entonces como puedo hacer para leer en el otro fichero el diccionario sc_keys?.

Comment: Simplemente no lo declares dentro de `if __name__ = '__main__'`